# Trouble getting a Stylish code to be page or domain-specific in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, google-plus, stylish

How do I make this Stylish code apply to only the domain plus.google.com in Firefox?

In Chrome, the Stylish extension allows you to specify for what domain a style should apply - but the Stylish extension for Firefox doesn't let you specify that as part of the extension.

I tried using `@-moz-document` rules as described on [this page](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish/wiki/Applying-styles-to-specific-sites), but that didn't seem to work.

Here's the code that I used - it is (despite my attempts) *not* specific to the plus.google.com domain:

```
@-moz-document  url-prefix(https://plus.google.com),
            domain(plus.google.com)
{
#contentPane > div {
text-align: center !important;
}

... ...

}
```

Please help?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Maybe you need to add the namespace?

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);  
@-moz-document domain('example.com')
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, use quotes for the domain and don't use `url-prefix` if it only covers the domain.

Comment: Still doesn't work, actually.  Thanks for the quick reply - could it be anything else?  I'm on Ffox 12.0.  Is there a different css extension besides Stylish that you could recommend?

Comment: Nope. Stylish is the best AFAIK. It's fast, easy to use, and has a semi-large userbase.

I have no idea why yours doesn't work, mine is identical to yours ( except for the url-prefix), but it doesn't work..

Comment: yeah, thanks @BrockAdams, but why the heck doublequotes dont work

Comment: @johnlowvale, Double-quotes do work; I use them almost exclusively.  If you have a problem, make an MCVE that demonstrates it and ask a new question (after searching for previous questions).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me it was a syntax error with the brackets. If you click the 'preview' button in the Stylish editor, it will tell you if there are any errors. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I use Stylish in Firefox to increase Reddit.com's default thumb size from 70px to 140px.

The top line tells Firefox to set the rule on a specific website.

**Note:** Don't forget to add the { at the end of the first line and } at the very end of the script.

```
@-moz-document domain("reddit.com") {
.thumbnail {
  width:auto;
  min-height:70px;
  max-height:none !important;}
.thumbnail img {
  width:140px;
  height:auto;
  border-radius: 0;}
a.thumbnail {
  width:auto;
  min-height:70px;}
a.thumbnail img{
  border-radius: 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck by not specifying the 'Applies to' section at the bottom of the edit section.
Select URLs on the domain - trello.com